# unexpected element <queries> found in manifest while building the project

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a Xamarin Forms project but it gives me this error in manifest file. My coworkers seem to build this project just fine so I think it's a problem with configuration on my machine. What could be the cause of such issue?

```
android:targetSdkVersion="29"
```

tried updating to 30, didn't help

Error lines:

```
 <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
```

Comment: I saw that your project target SDK version is Android 10.0, According to [Query & Interact with Apps in Android 11 with Package Visibility](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-11-package-visibility/), I think it is a feature of Android 11, please change your project sdk version Android 11 and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had version 10.0.99 and had to update Visual Studio to get an Android 11 option, that fixed the problem